# algebraic variety of dimension 0

Tags: algebraic-geometry

How to prove that if algebraic variety has zero dimension it must be finite set of points.
In other words: how to prove that it can't be infinite set ???

Definitions

**algebraic variety** V - if V is the common zero set of a polynomial system over Field K (polynomes from $K[x_1,...,x_n]$)

**dimension** of V is $ trdeg(K(V) : K)$, $K$ - is assumed to be algebraically closed

Comment: What is your definition of "variety" and "dimension?"

Comment: i added definitions in main post

Comment: Is $K$ assumed to be algebraically closed?

Comment: Andrew, yeap it is.

Comment: What is $K(V)$?  This might not make sense if $V$ is not irreducible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let's suppose that we've broken $V$ down into irreducible components, and therefore without loss of generality assume $V$ to be irreducible. I'll show that $V$ must be a single point.

Since the transcendence degree of $K(V)$ over $K$ is $0$, $K(V)$ must be an algebraic field extension of $K$. Since $K$ is algebraically closed, $K(V)$ must equal $K$. In particular, this means that the only regular functions on $V$ are constant polynomials; algebraically speaking, if $I \subset K[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ corresponds to $V$, then $K[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I= K$. This implies that $I$ is a maximal ideal; i.e. $V$ is a point.

---

$V$ must be a finite number of points because $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]$ is a Noetherian ring (see Hilbert Basis Theorem). This means there are no infinitely ascending chains $I_1 \subsetneq I_2 \subsetneq \cdots$. On the geometric side this means there are no infinite descending chains of subsets $X_1\supsetneq X_2\supsetneq\cdots$. So, if $V$ had an infinite number of points, we could form an infinite descending chain by peeling off one point at a time, a contradiction.

Comment: How it exactly work: "Since K is algebraically closed, K(V) must equal K" ???

Comment: This is a general field extension fact. If $L/K$ is algebraic and $K$ is algebraically closed, take $\alpha \in L$. Since it's algebraic, $\alpha$ is the root of a polynomial over $K$. Since $K$ is algebraically closed, $\alpha$ must be in $K$.

Comment: very useful thanks a lot:) it's so simple. may be you can help with this one https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2298132/complex-matrices-of-rank-not-greater-than-k-is-irreducible-algebraic-variety?noredirect=1#comment4728169_2298132

Comment: Andrew: but why initial V can't be infinite set of points ???

Comment: I'll edit my answer.