# Dimension 0 variety is a point

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $V$ be an irreducible variety of dimension 0 over an algebraically closed field $k$.

I understand that the function field $K(V)$ is equal to $k$. The answer to
[algebraic variety of dimension 0](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2298162/algebraic-variety-of-dimension-0) uses this fact to conclude that $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I_V=k$, where $I_V$ is the ideal of $V$. Why is this true?

(The definitions I am using are the same as those in the linked question.)

Comment: It is always the case that $K(V) = \text{Frac}(K[V])$ where $K[V] =  K[x_1,\ldots,x_n]/I_V$, $I_V= \{ f \in K[x_1,\ldots,x_n], \forall a \in V, f(a) = 0\}$. Here $K[V] \cong K$ thus
$K(V) = K[V]$ and $I_V= (x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_n)$.

Comment: I thought that $K(V)=\text{Frac}(K[V])$ only holds when $V$ is an affine variety. If this is true for all varieties, where may I find a proof?

Comment: Sorry I meant irreducible affine variety. For a projective variety you need an homogeneous prime ideal, the fraction field of the ring it generates, and the subfield of projective rational functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $V$ is irreducible, the algebra of functions $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/I_V$ embeds into the function field $K(V) = k$. This means that we have an injective map of $k$-algebras
$$ k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/I_V \to k$$
which has image $k$, and so by the isomorphism theorem $k[x_1, \ldots, x_n]/I_V \cong k$.

Comment: $V$ is irreducible thus it has a function field $K(V)$

Comment: Why is the injection $k[x_1,\dots,x_n]/I_Z\to k$ surjective?

Comment: It is a map of $k$-algebras, and so $k$ is always preserved. Alternatively, the only ideal of the polynomial ring containing $k$  is the unit ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addemdum, correct me if I am wrong:

Basically, dimension of $X$ is supremum of lenght $n$ of chains of irreducible subvarieties $X_0\supsetneq \cdots \supsetneq X_n \neq \emptyset $, where $X_n$ is a point (ie, is just possible to construct subvarieties by decreasing dimension). So, dimension is $0$ $\iff$ $X$ is a single point.