# Closure of image by polynomial of irreducible algebraic variety is also irreducible algebraic variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology

How to show that closure of image by polynomial of irreducible algebraic variety is also irreducible algebraic variety.

$A$ -irreducible algebraic variety, $F$ - polynomial map ($F:A \to B$), proof that $\bar B$ - is irreducible algebraic variety.

Closure of some set is always algebraic variety as definition of closure. But how to show, that is irreducible ???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two questions :

- The image of an irreducible subset is irreducible
- The closure of an irreducible subset is irreducible

Recall that a set $A \subset X$ irreducible if for any closed (for induced topology) subset $F_1, F_2 \subset A$, $A = F_1 \cup F_2 \Rightarrow A = F_1$ or $A = F_2$.

- First question : let $f : X \to Y$ continuous and $A \subset X$ irreducible. If $B := f(A)$ is not irreducible, there is two closed subset $F_1, F_2$ with $F_1 \neq B, F_2 \neq B$. Now the equality $A = f^{-1}(F_1) \cup f^{-1}F_2$ contradicts that $A$ was irreducible, which proves the first claim.
- Second question : let $A \subset X$ be an irreducible subset. Let $\overline A$ be the
  closure of $A$, we will show that $\overline A$ is irreducible.
  Again, assume that $F_1 \cup F_2 = \overline A$ are two proper closed
  subsets. Then, $F_1' := F_1 \cap A$ and $F_2' := F_2 \cap A$ are by
  definition proper closed subset of $A$, this shows that $A$ was not
  irreducible which is again a contradiction.

Finally, notice that the image of an algebraic variety by a polynomial map does **not** need to be a algebraic variety. The simplest example is the map $\Bbb C^2 \to \Bbb C^2, (z,w) \mapsto (z, zw)$.

Comment: I dislike "Irreducible set", and i can't find this definition. Irreducible algebraic variety is well defined object, as it can't be represented as union of others algebraic variety. If you define Irreducible set as union of algebraic closured sets, each of factors will be algebraic variety by definition. And hence any Irreducible set (which is not be algebraic variety) is irreducible. Can you show the question without using definition of Irreducible set, only with Irreducible algebraic variety?

Comment: Irreducible set is a _topological_ notion, and this is the good notion to adopt for solve this problem. I wrote the definition of irreducible set in my answer.

Comment: closed topologically ? $F_i$ are disjoint ?

Comment: Ok, your proof is nice. Anyway i can use this proof without irreducible sets:) Only using of fact of preimage is irreductible and image is not be represented with 2 closed sets.

Comment: $F_i$ are not necessarly disjoint. For example $xy = 0$ is connected but not irreducible. Glad I could help you :)

Comment: why is the image of the map (z,w)$\rightarrow$ (z,zw) not an algebraic variety?