# Compute the Zariski closure of a set

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, zariski-topology, projective-varieties

I have to compute the Zariski closure of the image of the following rational map:
$f:{P}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^4$ $[x_0:x_1:x_2]\rightarrow [x_0x_1:x_0x_2:x_1^2:x_1x_2:x_2^2]$

I have already proved that this map is a morphism from $U$ to $\mathbb{P}^4$, where $U=\mathbb{P}^2 \setminus  \{[1:0:0]\}$ and that cannot be extended to a map defined on the whole $\mathbb{P}^2$.

Now, I don't know how to compute the Zariski closure of $f(U)$.
I know the useful relation $\overline{S}=V(I(S))$ for a set $S$: does this mean that I have to compute the ideal of $f(U)$, or is there a better way?

Moreover, I am asked to say if this closure of $f(U)$ is irreducible and what is its dimension. I have already proved that the closure is irreducible if and only if $f(U)$ is irreducible, but I still do not know how to proceed.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to compute equations for the Zariski closure of the image is to find the kernel of the graded ring homomorphism $k[y_0,y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4]\to k[x_0,x_1,x_2]$ by $y_0\mapsto x_0x_1$, $y_1\mapsto x_0x_2$, $y_2\mapsto x_1^2$, $y_3\mapsto x_1x_2$, $y_4\mapsto x_2^2$. There are a few obvious relations coming from considering different products of $y_i$s which are equal after plugging in the $x_i$s, and it turns out that these obvious relations actually generate the kernel and cut out the closure (exercise: prove this).

You're almost there on the irreducibility - the only missing ingredient for you is that the image of an irreducible set is irreducible. For more details, see [here on MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2302484/closure-of-image-by-polynomial-of-irreducible-algebraic-variety-is-also-irreduci).

To find the dimension, you can work locally: on the affine open $D(y_4)$, you have a map $\Bbb A^2\to\Bbb A^4$ given by $(\frac{x_0}{x_2},\frac{x_1}{x_2})\mapsto (\frac{x_0x_1}{x_2^2},\frac{x_0}{x_2},\frac{x_1^2}{x_2^2},\frac{x_1}{x_2})$, which shows that the dimension of the image is 2.

Comment: For the "exercise: prove this" , do we just use Grobner basis? Otherwise I'm not even sure where to start.

Comment: @DavidLui sure, you can use Grobner bases - the computation shouldn't be awful since the relations are pretty simple. One can also tinker with the ideal sheaves of the image - you only have to look at two affine charts and the map is a closed immersion there.